# Highcharts bar chart wont animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation, highcharts

Not sure why because I have done it in the past, but I have a Highcharts bar chart and it won't animate. This is the declaration of the chart,

```
    function initializeData() {
      $http.get(url).success(function(ret) {
        $scope.jsondata = ret;
        var newdata = [];

        for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
          newdata.push({
            name: setName($scope.jsondata[x].name),
            y: $scope.jsondata[x].data[0],
            color: getColor($scope.jsondata[x].data[0])
          });
        }

        $scope.chart.series[0].setData(newdata);
      });
      mainInterval = $interval(updateData, 5000);
    }

    function updateData() {
      $http.get(url).success(function(ret) {
        $scope.jsondata = ret;
        console.debug("here");

        for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
          $scope.chart.series[0].data[x].update({
            y: $scope.jsondata[x].data[0],
            color: getColor($scope.jsondata[x].data[0])
          });
        }
      });
    }

    $scope.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'bar',
        animation: true,
        events: {
          load: initializeData
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
          style: {
            fontSize: '11px'
          }
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: {
          text: 'Total Score',
          align: 'high'
        }
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Total Score <b>{point.y:.3f}</b>'
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Active Users',
        data: [],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          rotation: 30,
          style: {
            fontSize: '10px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
          },
          format: '{point.y:.3f}', // one decimal
        }
      }]
    });
```

And as you can see I have `animate : true,` so I am not sure what is the problem here. [I have this older plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DO8d5W07RpTIcQ7cwhXD?p=preview) where all of the data is in separate series, but it animates fine. But [this is the plunker I am working on](http://plnkr.co/edit/JLiGQnfzgGR1ZJ9BeltT?p=preview) and having trouble with. They are like identical basically. In the newer one I broke out the initialization of data into its own method, but that is the only real main difference.

**Some edits:**

So as I was saying, I have done things this way with an areaspline chart (I know it was said they work a bit different but they are set up identically).

```
function initializeData() {
              $interval.cancel(mainInterval);
              $scope.previousPackets = '';
              $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/nodx").success(function(returnedData) {

                var newdata = [];

                var x = (new Date()).getTime();

                for (var step = 9; step >= 0; step--) {
                  newdata.push([x - 1000 * step, 0]);
                }

                $scope.chart.series[0].setData(newdata);
              });
              mainInterval = $interval(updateData, 2000);
            }

            function updateData() {
              $http.get(url + acronym + '/latest').success(function(returnedData) {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime();

                if ($scope.previousPackets != returnedData[0].numPackets) {
                  $scope.chart.series[0].addPoint([x, returnedData[0].numPackets], true, true);
                  $scope.previousPackets = returnedData[0].numPackets;
                } else {
                  $scope.chart.series[0].addPoint([x, 0], true, true);
                }

              });

            }

            $scope.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
              chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'areaspline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                  load: initializeData
                }
              },
              title: {
                text: ''
              },
              xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
              },
              yAxis: {
                title: {
                  text: 'Packets'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                  value: 0,
                  width: 1,
                  color: '#d9534f'
                }]
              },
              tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                  return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y) + ' packets<b> | </b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x);
                }
              },
              legend: {
                enabled: false
              },
              exporting: {
                enabled: false
              },
              series: [{
                name: 'Packets',
                data: []
              }]
            });
```

I also updated the first chunk of code with the `initializeData()` method and `updateData()` method which are seemingly identical in both different charts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it plays an important role if you provide your data at chart initialization or after. For simplicity I refactored your code a little

```
function initializeChart(initialData, onload) {
  $scope.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'bar',
      animation: true,
      events: {
        load: onload
      }
      ....
      series: [{
        name: 'Active Users',
        data: initialData,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.y:.3f}', // one decimal
        }
      }]
    });
  }

  function getData(callback) {
    $http.get(url).success(function(ret) {
      $scope.jsondata = ret;
      var newdata = [];

      for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        newdata.push([setName(ret[x].name), ret[x].data]);
      }

      callback(newdata);
    });
  }
```

As a result your two planks are in essense reduced to two methods below. The first initializes chart with preloaded data and the second updates data in existing chart.

```
function readDataFirst() {
  getData(function(newdata) {
    initializeChart(newdata);
  });
}

function initializeChartFirst() {
  initializeChart([], function() {
    getData(function(newdata) {
      $scope.chart.series[0].setData(newdata);
    })
  });
}
```

The first one animates fine while the second does not. It looks like highcharts skips animation if dataset is not initial and is treated incompatible.

However if you really want to have animation in your current plant (chart first workflow) you can achieve that by initializing first serie with zeros and then with the real data. This case it will be treated as update

```
function forceAnimationByDoubleInitialization() {
  getData(function(newdata) {
    initializeChart([]);
    var zerodata = newdata.map(function(item) {
      return [item[0], 0]
    });

    $scope.chart.series[0].setData(zerodata);
    $scope.chart.series[0].setData(newdata);
  });
```

All these options are available at http://plnkr.co/edit/pZhBJoV7PmjDNRNOj2Uc

Comment: So are you saying that since I dont have the data at the point of initialization it doesn't animate?

Comment: Based on this small test I believe it animates either if you construct new chart object or if it treats new dataset as a "change" of the existing. If it is too different no animation happen.

Comment: Hm yeah. It's weird because I have done it this way before with a spline chart and the initialization method. I mean this chart animates when data is refreshed fine (new data) using the `update` method.

Comment: I feel that this wierd behavior is specific (or at least much easier to achieve) for category charts. BTW update doesn't help here as well

Comment: I tried recently a couple of official highchart bar chart exsamples and they do animation only if initialized or if updated with exactly the same list of categories. Thus it is surely not a fail in code but general strategy

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Check op for a bit more info.

Comment: That's correct. There is only one initial animation, when chart is created. Later when you set new data, animation is different, and when setting data for empty series, it won't animate as new series. Instead of `setData()` you can use `chart.addSeries()` - that will animate properly. Like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4NqtyG4paH9s272MtSM?p=preview

Comment: Small correction for the above, it's different animation for new series, not for a new chart. That's why you can get animation when using `addSeries()`.